# join multiple subqueries that returns one or more rows in vertical table

Tags: mysql, join, row

I have large MySQL vertical table named 'profile_features' like this:

| id | Profile_id | feature_id | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | Rick |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | Novak |
| 3 | 5 | 3 | 5428 |
| 4 | 5 | 1 | Joe |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

(above table is short part of all data)

how can I find specific Profile_ids that have ALL below conditions:
(meeting the 1st AND Second And Third condition).
and I want all profile_ids as result.

```
 profile_id FROM profile_features WHERE( feature_id IN(2, 64, 90, 38, 73, 115) AND value ='Joe')
AND
 profile_id FROM profile_features WHERE( feature_id IN(1, 55, 86, 23, 72, 114) AND value ='US')
AND
 profile_id FROM profile_features WHERE( feature_id IN(4, 59, 98, 43, 78, 120) AND value ='54782')
```

Comment: What is the problem with your current SQL query?

Comment: I don't know how to use AND between this subqueries. each of them returns multiple results (rows).

Comment: So contrary to what you wrote, you *don't* want "Profile_ids that have all these conditions". What ones *do* you want? PS (Clearly,) When clear this will be a faq. Please before considering posting read the manual/reference & google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. Reflect your research.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For errors that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. [ask] [Help]

Comment: Your edits didn't improve anything. There are no "Profile_ids that have ALL these conditions" since none is equal to 3 different strings. And the 1st 2 comments above seem to show you know this. You seem to want the profiles meeting the 1st condition AND you want the ones meeting the 2nd AND etc. But that's not what you say. Edit your post to actually say what you mean. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. You can't expect to reason, ask or code yourself if you aren't clear. PS I have an id. Under what condition do you want it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aggregate by profile and then use three separate assertions in the `HAVING` clause for your criteria:

```sql
SELECT profile_id
FROM profile_features
GROUP BY profile_id
HAVING SUM(feature_id IN (2, 64, 90, 38, 73, 115) AND value = 'Joe') > 0 AND
       SUM(feature_id IN (1, 55, 86, 23, 72, 114) AND value = 'US') > 0  AND
       SUM(feature_id IN (4, 59, 98, 43, 78, 120) AND value = '54782') > 0;
```

Comment: I want Profile_id that exists in all subqueries, I can not use OR. All condition must be true

Comment: Check the updated answer.  You may use aggregation here.  Your original question did not make it completely clear what you want here.